# What's the grammatical structure of "hard as that is to believe" in this context?

Tags: grammar

> "Enough to bring joy to the most joyless critics, isn't she?"
>
> "Mmm. And in the hands of a real purveyor of the arts, she could be something in this country. Shame, she's fallen in with you."
>
> "(laugh)You really are better on the page, Mr. Bennett, **hard as that is to believe**."
>
> *The Greatest Showman*

What's the grammatical structure of "hard as that is to believe" here?

I guess he's being offensive to the critic because the critic provoked him first. So I understand what this means but I don't understand the grammar of "hard as that is to believe".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Grammatically, it's an adjunct of concession. To understand it fully, I think we have to treat "as" as an adverb here with a meaning equivalent to "though", as in "hard though that is to believe". In more detail, it exhibits preposing of the adjective "hard": the basic version would be "though that is hard to believe".

Comment: We also say ***as* hard as that is to believe**. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20hard%20as%20that%20is%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Scattered among the results here you will find a similar pattern: (**heavy as it was**): https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heavy%20as%20it%20was%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"As hard as that is to believe" is an idiomatic expression that means *"Even though [something] seems unbelievable, nevertheless it is true."*  In itself, it's not insulting, but instead depends on context for its meaning.  Example:

> I've run ten marathons in the past month, **as hard as that is to believe.**

I haven't seen *The Greatest Showman* but it seems first Barnum (I assume it's Barnum talking) insults Bennett by insinuating he is one of the most "joyless" critics -- that nothing will please him.  Bennett retorts that the performer is truly talented, so it's a shame she's working with Barnum (who lacks talent).

Barnum then good-naturedly teases Bennett by saying he is a more likable person "on the page" (meaning in his printed articles) than he is in person -- which is difficult to believe, since  Bennett is not very likable in print, *yet is somehow even more offensive in person.*

I can't tell from this brief exchange whether the two are trading *friendly [gibes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gibe)*, or if they honestly don't like each other and are masking their dislike with *polite [witticisms](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/witticism)*.